# How to add plugs to switchboard in NixOS?

Tags: nixos

In NixOS 22.05 (Quokka) I want to add a plug to switchboard to be able to manage users (e.g. set a profile picture). I know I have to configure the extra switchboard plugs in the `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file:

`services.xserver.desktopManager.pantheon.extraSwitchboardPlugs = [];`

But I have no clue, what the plug names are that I have to mention between `[]`. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 0):

This option, as documented on [NixOS search](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=22.05&show=services.xserver.desktopManager.pantheon.extraSwitchboardPlugs&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=pantheon.extraSwitchboardPlugs), takes a `list of package` -- that is, a list of Nix derivations.

Your list would look like this:

```hs
services.xserver.desktopManager.pantheon.extraSwitchboardPlugs =
  [ pkgs.switchboard-plug-power ];
```

It would appear that the user accounts plug just hasn't been added to NixOS. On [NixOS package search](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=switchboard-plug-power), clicking "Source", we see that the source file where another Switchboard plug is declared is on their GitHub repository, under [`/pkgs/desktops/pantheon/apps/switchboard-plugs/power/`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-22.05/pkgs/desktops/pantheon/apps/switchboard-plugs/power/default.nix#L57) for instance.

Looking in the parent directory, there is no mention of the Users plug. You can try writing your own derivation for it, by using the Power plug I listed above as an example.